# Using multiple databases in one connection

Tags: python, postgresql, python-asyncio, psycopg2, asyncpg

I want to make a single class for interacting with the database, but so that one pool is used (implemented through the singleton pattern), but at the same time, so that I can switch between databases without recreating the connection.

That is, I take a connection, then I use acquire through the with context manager, and then I want to connect to a specific database. How can I do it?

```
class ConnectionPool:
    _instance = None

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls._instance is None:
            cls._instance = super().__new__(cls)
        return cls._instance

    async def init(self):
        self.pool = await asyncpg.create_pool(
            dsn=f"postgres://{cfg.DB_USER}:{cfg.DB_PASSWORD}@{cfg.DB_HOST}:{cfg.DB_PORT}"
        )

    async def acquire(self):
        conn = await self.pool.acquire()
        return conn

    async def release(self, conn):
        await self.pool.release(conn)
```

Here is a class, it is initialized once, creates the main pool, and then simply distributes connections in which I already want to connect to a specific database and use it.

Well, or you can offer your own implementation. The main thing that I need - the minimum load on the system. Using multiple databases.

Already wrote everything above.Multiple databases in one asyncpg connection

Comment: Cant your class just have a pool for each db? so you could then access the pool for each db through a dict

Comment: having a separate connection pool for each db would also minimise the system load more (ensuring efficient utilization of resources and minimizing the impact on the overall system performance). using a dict would be a better approach (as @ChrisDoyle commented)

Comment: No, not in PostgreSQL.  You probably want to use schemas, not databases, for this purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Once you have established a connection to a PostgreSQL database, you cannot switch to a different database unless you close the old connection and open a new one. So you will need one connection pool per database.

If you want a documentation reference, [here goes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/manage-ag-overview.html):

> When connecting to the database server, a client must specify the database name in its connection request. It is not possible to access more than one database per connection.

Comment: Are you sure it's not possible to do this?

Comment: Yes, quite sure. Since I realize that my word alone is not convincing, I have added a link to the documentation.